# How to get a robot position (x,y) in a map instead of Odometry in python?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to record robot position (x,y) in a map instead of  Odometry in python  because my Odometry is not accurate, I asked yesterday about this issue [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/341007/how-to-reduce-the-error-in-position-by-odom/). So, I need to record them from the map.

when I am using this command in a terminal, I see a good accuracy

```
rosrun tf tf_echo /map /base_link
```

how to get information of this command in python

my code when I use the Odometry:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry


class OdometryModifier:

  def __init__(self):
    self.sub = rospy.Subscriber("odom", Odometry, self.callback)
  def callback(self, data):
    x = data.pose.pose.position.x
    y = data.pose.pose.position.y
    with open("target.csv", "a") as text_file:
        text_file.write("\n%.3f" % (x))
        text_file.write("\t%.3f" % (y))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('move_turtlebot', anonymous=True)
    try:
        odom = OdometryModifier()
        rospy.spin()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        rospy.loginfo('Shutting down')
```

how to get only information `print position, quaternion`

**Update1**

I updated my question after @billy's answer

the issue not in using google, tf isn't familiar with me.

```
import rospy
from tf import TransformListener
from geometry_msgs.msg import PointStamped
# from nav_msgs.msg import OccupancyGrid

class myNode:

    def __init__(self):
        self.tf = TransformListener()
        self.sub = rospy.Subscriber("/tf", PointStamped, self.some_method)
        # rospy.Subscriber("/map", TransformStamped, )
        # ...

    def some_method(self, point_stamped):
        print point_stamped

        if self.tf.frameExists("/base_link") and self.tf.frameExists("/map"):
            t = self.tf.getLatestCommonTime("/base_link", "/map")
            position, quaternion = self.tf.lookupTransform("/base_link", "/map", t)
            print position, quaternion
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('move_turtlebot', anonymous=True)
    try:
        odom = myNode()
        rospy.spin()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        rospy.loginfo('Shutting down')
```

the output `print point_stamped`

```
.....
....
....

transforms: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1578296497
        nsecs: 454806328
      frame_id: "odom"
    child_frame_id: "base_link"
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: -0.000629110541654
        y: 7.50070441544e-06
        z: 0.0
      rotation: 
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.0
        z: 0.0161632095368
        w: 0.999869366796
transforms: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1578296498
        nsecs: 123375996
      frame_id: "map"
    child_frame_id: "odom"
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: -0.0020397693567
        y: 0.00738271227423
        z: 0.0
      rotation: 
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.0
        z: -0.0116367688543
        w: 0.999932290513transforms: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 1578296497
        nsecs: 971281007
      frame_id: "/camera_link"
    child_frame_id: "/camera_depth_frame"
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: 0.0
        y: -0.02
        z: 0.0
      rotation: 
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.0
        z: 0.0
        w: 1.0
      ......
       ....
```

**Update2**

The output `print self.tf.allFramesAsString()`

I see    `Frame odom exists with parent map`.

```
Frame RIA_TOP_FRAME exists with parent RIA_BASE.
Frame RIA_BASE exists with parent base_link.
Frame base_link exists with parent odom.
Frame camera_link exists with parent base_link.
Frame imu_link exists with parent base_link.
Frame laser_link exists with parent base_link.
Frame camera_depth_frame exists with parent camera_link.
Frame camera_depth_optical_frame exists with parent camera_depth_frame.
Frame camera_rgb_frame exists with parent camera_link.
Frame camera_rgb_optical_frame exists with parent camera_rgb_frame.
Frame rear_left_wheel exists with parent base_link.
Frame rear_right_wheel exists with parent base_link.
Frame map_ned exists with parent map.
Frame odom_ned exists with parent odom.
Frame odom exists with parent map.
Frame base_link_frd exists with parent base_link.
Frame front_left_wheel exists with parent base_link.
Frame front_right_wheel exists with parent base_link.
```

The output `print position`

[image: image description]

The output `print point_stamped`

[image: image description]

The output in TERMINAL  `rosrun tf tf_echo /odom /base_link`

[image: image description]

You can see the difference between the output of `print position` and the output of `print point_stamped`

There are not different between the output of `print point_stamped` and  The output in TERMINAL  `rosrun tf tf_echo /odom /base_link` **SORRY**  I see some difference between them today.

I think that some wrong in the code or purpose this code for another thing

ALSO ANOTHER ISSUE  the output the same when the robot moves but when stop running the code and run it again, it updates the output. I think that it needs to use `rospy.Time.now()`

I think something loses in this line `t = self.tf.getLatestCommonTime("base_link", "odom")`

I have `/odom_ekf` in my system, its output is the same `print point_stamped`. it combined between a map and odometry.

please help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341062/how-to-get-a-robot-position-(x,y)-in-a-map-instead-of-odometry-in-python?/) by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2020-01-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this code fix it,  I got it [here](https://github.com/socrob/autonomous_systems/blob/master/lab2/tf_listener_tutorial.py)

the same output: `rosrun tf tf_echo /map /base_link`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import tf

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # initialize node
    rospy.init_node('tf_listener')
    # print in console that the node is running
    rospy.loginfo('started listener node !')
    # create tf listener
    listener = tf.TransformListener()
    # set the node to run 1 time per second (1 hz)
    rate = rospy.Rate(1.0)
    # loop forever until roscore or this node is down
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        try:
            # listen to transform
            (trans,rot) = listener.lookupTransform('/map', '/base_link', rospy.Time(0))
            # print the transform
            rospy.loginfo('---------')
            rospy.loginfo('Translation: ' + str(trans))
            rospy.loginfo('Rotation: ' + str(rot))
        except (tf.LookupException, tf.ConnectivityException, tf.ExtrapolationException):
            continue
        # sleep to control the node frequency
        rate.sleep()
```

---

Originally posted by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) with karma: 73 on 2020-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2020-01-08**:
simple, thanks for updating

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2020-01-08**:
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From this page: http://wiki.ros.org/tf/TfUsingPython

```
import rospy
from tf import TransformListener

class myNode:

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.tf = TransformListener()
        rospy.Subscriber(...)
        ...

    def some_method(self):
        if self.tf.frameExists("/base_link") and self.tf.frameExists("/map"):
            t = self.tf.getLatestCommonTime("/base_link", "/map")
            position, quaternion = self.tf.lookupTransform("/base_link", "/map", t)
            print position, quaternion
```

This took about 23 seconds to find using google, most of that because I am slow on the keyboard. I encourage you to use google (unless you're in china in which case you cannot use google). It will be much faster than asking questions and waiting for answers.

**EDIT AFTER ADDITIONAL QUESTION AND INFO ADDED TO OP:**

OK, are you sitting down? That code doesn't work on my machine. But maybe it will on yours.

Since your frames names do not include '/', you should use `base_link` instead of `/base_link` in the python code.  That change will make the
`if self.tf.frameExists("base_link")` part of the conditional TRUE.  Remove all the "/"s from the python and see if that fixes it.

On my machine (ROS JADE on 14.04) **the `self.tf.frameExists("map")` will never be true**. That function only works on the child_frame_id field on my machine.

Stick `print self.tf.allFramesAsString()` in your code in place of the `print point_stamped` and see what you get back out. What I get is:

```
Frame laser exists with parent base_link.
Frame base_link exists with parent odom.
Frame imu exists with parent base_link.
Frame odom exists with parent map.
```

You can see there is no Frame called "`map`" so that part of the conditional is never true. Looks like I gave you some bad advice when referring you to this code.

If you figure out how to get a conditional that is capable of referencing the frame_id instead of the child_frame_id, please write back. I have no need for this info but now I'm frustrated and simply want to know.

Back to your original question:

You specifically asked about doing this in python so I didn't say anything about the robot pose publisher node: http://wiki.ros.org/robot_pose_publisher. It will give you the data you want on a topic that you can subscribe to. I think it's part of the binary install but written in C++. But you can read the topic "robot_pose" in python and do what you want.

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2020-01-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2020-01-06**:
first of all, thank you so much @billy.
I updated my question after your answer.
I can't see any output even though I launched the map and robot. what is wrong??
please help me more.

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2020-01-06**:
I can check later what's required to get it working - but can you please let me know what steps you took to troubleshoot?

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2020-01-06**:
Thank you @billy,  I will wait and I will appreciate your help

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2020-01-07**:
updated my answer with new info and alternate method to use.

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2020-01-07**:
Thank you so much from my bottom heart, some progress happened after your answer's update
I will wrote them here after  2 or 3 hours.